# Google Home App Development local device access

Tags: node.js, networking, google-home

I have a embedded temp. controller which has a HTTP server but doesn't have any internet connection. 
Can someone confirm if it is possible to make a google home app which can perform HTTP action to local device (In this case temp controller) [Assuming temp controller local IP Address is known(local WiFi network IP) and they both are in same network].

I have tried searching but didn't get a concrete answer. I can think they want to restrict direct local access of devices because it could be a security issue.

Please let me know and thanks for help

Comment: I think you can do it with google local-home-sdk now. check this out https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't do that.

The Google Home uses cloud-based controls to do home automation. It doesn't try to do anything on the local network. Most home automation systems have a cloud-based component so you can control your home while you're away from it (turn up the heat when you're leaving work, for example), and the Home takes advantage of this.